# GCC Linaro cross compile fails on linker step on a Windows host

Tags: gcc, build, arm, cross-compiling, linaro

I want to build an ARM application(just a simple main function) on Windows host using GCC Linaro toolchains version 7.4.1.
Compilation is OK, my .o files are created but on linking step I get the following errors(tested on different computers and result is same)

Errors start from locale.o file... But that /home/tcwg-builds/.. directory is not related to my computer paths...

Building target: arm_cpp
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
arm-eabi-g++  -o "arm_cpp"  ./src/arm_cpp.o
c:/users/yunus/desktop/linarotoolchain/gcc_linaro_7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/7.4.1/../../../../arm-eabi/lib\libstdc++.a(locale.o): In function `get_locale_cache_mutex':
/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release_0/snapshots/gcc.git~linaro-7.4-2019.02/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/locale.cc:36: undefined reference to`__sync_synchronize'
c:/users/yunus/desktop/linarotoolchain/gcc_linaro_7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/7.4.1/../../../../arm-eabi/lib\libstdc++.a(locale_init.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::get_locale_mutex()':
/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release_0/snapshots/gcc.git~linaro-7.4-2019.02/libstdc++-v3/src/c++98/locale_init.cc:66: undefined reference to`__sync_synchronize'
c:/users/yunus/desktop/linarotoolchain/gcc_linaro_7/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-eabi/7.4.1/../../../../arm-eabi/lib\libstdc++.a(cxx11-ios_failure.o): In function `(anonymous namespace)::__io_category_instance()':
/home/tcwg-buildslave/workspace/tcwg-make-release_0/snapshots/gcc.git~linaro-7.4-2019.02/libstdc++-v3/src/c++11/cxx11-ios_failure.cc:73: undefined reference to`__sync_synchronize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [arm_cpp] Error 1
"make all" terminated with exit code 2. Build might be incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really searched this problem for days but now I immeditely find the answer, from this thread: https://lists.linaro.org/pipermail/linaro-toolchain/2018-January/006356.html

It is stated that:

> This error happens because the arm-eabi compiler defaults to an old
>   version of the architecture (v4 or v5t). Adding -mcpu=cortex-a9 for
>   instance should avoid the problem because the compiler will be able to
>   generate synchronization primitives inline.

With this linking option I succesfully get result image without errors